# The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK_Claims_Patients"

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, foreign-keys

I'm trying to delete a "person" from my website TABLE but I'm getting error, written in the title of post, and the error is pointing me to this code:

```
Patient patient = db.Patients.Single(p => p.Patient id == id);
db.Patients.Remove(patient);
db.SaveChanges();
return RedirectToAction("Index");
```

Or, if possible, how can I add an exception, so when i click on delete button, it will open another page and tell me, that I don't have a rights to delete that person.

Any idea's?

Answer (score 11):

You need to delete all claims that reference that patient.  One way to accomplish this is to add cascading deletes to your foreign key constraint, however, I don't know which DBMS you're using.

The error message seems to suggest SQL Server, so here's some info for SQL Server - [Cascading Referential Integrity Constraints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933119%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)

To fix this for your situation, you'll want to perform a DROP CONSTRAINT, then an ADD CONSTAINT.

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Claims
   DROP CONSTRAINT FK_Claims_Patients

ALTER TABLE dbo.Claims
   ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Claims_Patients
   FOREIGN KEY (PatientId) REFERENCES dbo.Patients(PatientId) ON DELETE CASCADE
```

Comment: thanks chris: but how can l add the cascading delete to my foreign key? l mean the codes of adding it. am using Microsoft sql server 2008.

Comment: Without knowing which DBMS you're using, it's difficult to say.

Comment: Am using Microsoft SQL Server 2008.

Comment: @UmarBachena - I took a guess at your table structure, but what I have should take care of your problem.  Also note, that any other foreign keys to the Patients table will have to be corrected in the same manor.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you Chris.

Comment: @ChrisGesslerI am trying to set the property to NULL, as requirement is that foreign key attribute column should be set to null in case parent is deleted. however it throws the same exception as in OP. My foreign key attribute is nullable, and as per MS doc https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/cascade-delete  it says that if FK is nullable then i should be able to set this column to null. However, i get the same exception as in OP !

Answer (score 0):

```
Patient patient = db.Patients.Single(p => p.Patient id == id);
patient.Claims.clear();
db.Patients.Remove(patient);
db.SaveChanges();
```

Will delete related items in the link table and allow the delete.